# Adding a title to thumbnails using PHP

Tags: php

Simple PHP problem, someone may be able to help me with quickly:

Below is the PHP which controls what is displayed for the thumbnails on [this page](http://1073779888.n56898.test.prositehosting.co.uk/paintings.php)

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $no_of_posts + 1; $i++) {

     if ($image[$i][1] == $gallery) { 
    echo '<a href="http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'/'. $pulse_dir .'/data/img/gallery/'. $gallery .'/'. $image[$i][2] .'" title="'. $image[$i][3] .'" >' . "\n";
    echo '<img src="http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'/'. $pulse_dir .'/data/img/gallery/'.$gallery .'/'."thumb.php?src=" .$image[$i][2].'&h='.$height.'&w='.$width.'" alt="'. $image[$i][3] .'">';
    echo '</a>' . "\n\n";

    }
}
```

I just want to add the image title underneath each thumbnail.

Should be simple. Pulled enough hair out for the day.

You can see the thumbnails do have titles (when you roll over or click them you can see the title).  But how to display the title under the thumbnail?

Comment: try `title` attribute like `<img title='This will be displayed when hover the image' src=...>`

Comment: Do you mean positioning the alt text box under the image itself?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo '<br />' . $image[$i][3];
```

after

```
echo '<img src="http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'/'. $pulse_dir .'/data/img/gallery/'.$gallery .'/'."thumb.php?src=" .$image[$i][2].'&h='.$height.'&w='.$width.'" alt="'. $image[$i][3] .'">';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $no_of_posts + 1; $i++) {
     if ($image[$i][1] == $gallery) { 
    echo '<a href="http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'/'. $pulse_dir .'/data/img/gallery/'. $gallery .'/'. $image[$i][2] .'" title="'. $image[$i][3] .'" >' . "\n";
    echo '<img src="http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'/'. $pulse_dir .'/data/img/gallery/'.$gallery .'/'."thumb.php?src=" .$image[$i][2].'&h='.$height.'&w='.$width.'" alt="'. $image[$i][3] .'">';
    echo '</a>' . '<br /><span class="GIVE ME A CLASS">' .$image[$i][3]. '</span>'. "\n\n";

    }
}
```

This will give you the desired result while wrapping the title with a span so that you can actually throw some styling at it later on.